# How can I create a formatted and annotated excel with embedded pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I want to create a "presentation ready" excel document with embedded pandas DataFrames and additional data and formatting

A typical document will include some titles and meta data, several Data Frames with sum row\column for each data frame.

The DataFrame itself should be formatted

The best thing I found was [this](http://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html) which explains how to use pandas with XlsxWriter.

The main problem is that there's no apparent method to get the exact location of the embedded DataFrame to add the summary row below (the shape of the DataFrame is a good estimate, but it might no be exact when rendering complex DataFrames.

If there's a solution that relies on some kind of template, and not hard coding it would be even better.